# Binary operators to use in switch statement

Tags: php, refactoring

I have 2 boolean variables `$products_changed` and `$address_changed`.

I want to display a visual indicator for each of the statuses:

- both are true
- only `products_changed` is true
- only `address_changed` is true

Currently I'm doing:

```
  if ($products_changed && $address_changed) //if both have changed
  {
    //visual indicator for both
  }
  elseif ($products_changed) //only products changed
  {
    //visual indicator for products changed
  }
  elseif ($address_changed)  //only address changed
  {
    //visual indicator for address changed
  }
```

I need a logical/math operator that I can apply and will contain in the result whether both are true or both are false. However, if only one is true - I need to know which one (first or second).

This how I'd like to refactor my code:

```
const BOTH_CHANGED = 1, PRODUCTS_CHANGED = 2, ADDRESS_CHANGED = 3;
//The numbers 1,2,3 are arbitrary, could be any numbers.

$visual_indicator = $products_changed **SOME_OPERATOR** $address_changed;

switch( $visual_indicator) {
  case BOTH_CHANGED: //display visual indicator for both changed
   break;
  case PRODUCTS_CHANGED: //display visual indicator for products changed
   break;   
  case ADDRESS_CHANGED: //display visual indicator for address changed
   break; 
}
```

I realize I could do:

```
$visual_indicator = (int)$products_changed * 10 + (int)$address_changed;
//11 will be both changed, 10 will be products changed, 1 will be address changed
```

However I'm looking for a more elegant and possibly native operator.
This is important for both reducing code redundancy and readability (this is of course a simplified version of my code so in my own project this would have better implications).

Help & ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `xor`? "One or the other but not both" would give you "only one has changed".

Comment: @MarcB but *which* one is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For things like this I use bitwise operators. Something like the following:

```
    <?php

    // shift each option by 1
    define('A', 1);
    define('B', 1<<1);
    define('C', 1<<2);

    // combine opitons with bitwise or (|)
    $c = A | C;

    // compare with or'ed values to find the combination
    switch ($c) {
      case A:
        print "A only\n";
        break;
      case A|B:
        print "A and B\n";
        break;
      case A|C:
        print "A and C\n";
        break;
    }

    // use bitwise and (&) to check if an option is present
    if ($c & A) print "Has A\n";
    if ($c & B) print "Has B\n";
    if ($c & C) print "Has C\n";
```